# Changing font colour depending on url in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a simple footer component using tailwindcss

```
import React from "react"
import { FaMixcloud, FaFacebookSquare, FaTwitter } from "react-icons/fa"

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className="w-full fixed bottom-0 px-4 sm:px-10 py-6 flex justify-between items-center">
      <div className="text-white text-xs font-mono uppercase">
        &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} adam lawther
      </div>
      <nav className="flex items-center">
        <FaMixcloud className="h-6 w-6 mr-4 text-white" />
        <FaFacebookSquare className="h-4 w-4 mr-4 text-white" />
        <FaTwitter className="h-4 w-4 text-white" />
      </nav>
    </footer>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

On the homepage the text is white, which is what I am after...but on other pages, which dont have a full size image. The font is white, how can i change the css class id the url is not / (index.js)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [@reach/router](https://reach.tech/router/api/Location) (is what Gatsby's `<Link>` component uses and how React builds and keeps the logic between links and pages). Once you've installed and imported the package, you can use a `location` consumer to get what you need safely inside it, because it will expose a `location` object with all the information you need. Just like:

```
return <Location>
  {({ location })=> {
     let textColor=location.pathname === '/' ? 'text-white' : 'text-gray-500'

        <footer className="w-full fixed bottom-0 px-4 sm:px-10 py-6 flex justify-between items-center">
      <div className=`${textColor} text-xs font-mono uppercase`>
        &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} adam lawther
      </div>
      <nav className="flex items-center">
        <FaMixcloud className=`h-6 w-6 mr-4 ${textColor}` />
        <FaFacebookSquare className=`h-6 w-6 mr-4 ${textColor}` />
        <FaTwitter className=`h-6 w-6 mr-4 ${textColor}` />
      </nav>
    </footer>
  }}
</Location>
```

You can check for other options in https://css-tricks.com/how-to-the-get-current-page-url-in-gatsby/

Keep in mind that accessing directly to the `window` object may cause a break of your site since it's not defined at the runtime (check it in a `build` mode) so, you will need to check first if it's defined to render and execute the rest of your code logic, dirtying the code and making less clear and scalable.